# Is it possible to exclude some of the string used to match from Ruby regexp data?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a bunch of strings that look, for example, like this:

```
<option value="Spain">Spain</option>
```

And I want to extract the name of the country from inside.

The easiest way I could think of to do this in Ruby was to use a regular expression of this form:

```
country  = line.match(/>(.+)</)
```

However, this returns `>Spain<`. So I did this:

```
line.match(/>(.+)</).to_s.gsub!(/<|>/,"")
```

Works well enough, but I'd be surprised if there's not a more elegant way to do this? It seems like using a regular expression to declare how to find the thing you want, without actually wanting the enclosing strings that were used to match it to be part of the data that gets returned.

Is there a conventional approach to this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right way to deal with that string is to use an HTML parser, for example:

```
country = Nokogiri::HTML('<option value="Spain">Spain</option>').at('option').text
```

And if you have several such strings, paste them together and use `search`:

```
html      = '<option value="Spain">Spain</option><option value="Canada">Canada</option>'
countries = Nokogiri::HTML(html).search('option').map(&:text)
# ["Spain", "Canada"]
```

But if you must use a regex, then:

```
country = '<option value="Spain">Spain</option>'.match('>([^<]+)<')[1]
```

Keep in mind that [`match`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001136) actually returns a [MatchData](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/MatchData.html) object and [`MatchData#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/MatchData.html#M000412):

> Returns the entire matched string.

But you can access the captured groups using [`MatchData#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/MatchData.html#M000407). And if you don't like counting, you could use a named capture group as well:

```
country = '<option value="Spain">Spain</option>'.match('>(?<name>[^<]+)<')['name']
```

Comment: "The right way to deal with that string is to use an HTML parser" of course, silly me! I even read that famous post on how you absolutely must not ever used regexp to parse HTML recently.

Comment: @Cerales: You can use regexes for HTML mangling if you are absolutely certain that the HTML will be in a specific known format. I also added a little update in case you want to deal with multiple `<option>` elements at once with Nokogiri.